# how slove strapi-mail problem with sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid, strapi

when i am trying any operation related to the  mail service it gives me error

```
{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": 500,
        "name": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Internal Server Error"
    }
}
```

```
error: Forbidden
Error: Forbidden
    at C:\Strapi Project\demo test\my-project\node_modules\@sendgrid\client\src\classes\client.js:146:29
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

i have plugin the service

```
 email: {
    config: {
      provider: 'sendgrid',
      providerOptions: {
        apiKey: env('SENDGRID_API_KEY'),
      },
      settings: {
        defaultFrom: 'vik@open-infotech.com',
        defaultReplyTo: 'vik@open-infotech.com',
      },
    },
  },


 }
```

please give any suggection

Comment: you need to enable domain verifications permissions in sendgrid website